In MySQL why := is executed inside of case statement even if the condition is False and how can I fix this?
This problem I am trying to solve on HackerRank. In this problem, I have to group consecutive dates. Two dates are consecutive when the difference between two dates is 1 and in this problem statement, the start date and end date are always consecutive.
My approach is to group the consecutive dates. To identify the consecutive dates I am using a variable @rn. When the current start date is equal to the previous end date then I will have the same rn otherwise I am incrementing rn. Then I wanted to group by rn and get the min(start date) and max(end date) from each group with the same rn. But before implementing this logic I was facing an issue with the @rn variable being incremented even when the when condition is false inside of the case clause in MySQL.
set @rn = 0;

with tasks as (
    select distinct Start_Date, End_Date
    from Projects
    order by Start_Date
)

select
Start_Date, End_Date,
case 
when lag(End_Date, 1) over(Order by Start_Date) != Start_Date then @rn:=@rn+1
else @rn
end as cnt
from tasks

In the above query @rn := @rn+1 is executed even when the when condition is false.
I encountered this issue which trying to solve a problem from HackeRank.
If someone can explain why @run := @rn+1 is executed even when the condition is false it would be great.
Here is the output that the above query is generating for the specified problem :
Output I got :
2015-10-01 2015-10-02 0

2015-10-02 2015-10-03 1

2015-10-03 2015-10-04 2

2015-10-04 2015-10-05 3

2015-10-11 2015-10-12 24

2015-10-12 2015-10-13 5

2015-10-15 2015-10-16 24

2015-10-17 2015-10-18 24

2015-10-19 2015-10-20 24

2015-10-21 2015-10-22 24

2015-10-25 2015-10-26 24

...

Output I am expecting
2015-10-01 2015-10-02 1

2015-10-02 2015-10-03 1

2015-10-03 2015-10-04 1

2015-10-04 2015-10-05 1

2015-10-11 2015-10-12 2

2015-10-12 2015-10-13 2

2015-10-15 2015-10-16 3

2015-10-17 2015-10-18 4

2015-10-19 2015-10-20 5

2015-10-21 2015-10-22 6

2015-10-25 2015-10-26 7

...


You never included a proper problem statement, but that aside, using user variables is almost certainly unneeded here, given that you are clearly on MySQL 8+.

Thanks @TimBiegeleisen I will add the problem statement and an explanation for the above query.

What is the actual output you want?

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

@TimBiegeleisen I have added the output that I am expecting.

MySQL 8 - user variables within expressions is deprecated

Don't use variables. They are deprecated now.

Given that you are using MySQL 8+, which makes available the window functions, there isn't even any need to resort to using session/user variables.  With the help of window functions, your query is actually straightforward to phrase:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(End_Date) OVER (ORDER BY Start_Date) != Start_Date
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cnt
    FROM tasks
)

SELECT Start_Date, End_Date, 1 + SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY Start_Date) AS total
FROM cte
ORDER BY Start_Date;


But can you please also explain why is @rn:=@rn + 1 is executed even when the condition is false?

I don't know what the behavior of @rn would be when used inside a window function.  The MySQL documentation might explain this, but the best approach here on MySQL 8+ would be something along the lines of my answer.

Prior to mysql 8 the way to do this was using a cross join
select t.start_date,t.end_date,
        if(end_date > date_add(@dt ,interval 1 day) ,@rn:=@rn+1,@rn:=@rn) cnt,
        @dt := end_date
from t 
cross join (select @rn:=1,@dt:='2021-01-01') r
order by start_date;

https://dbfiddle.uk/FZMrDDnb

Your query does not function as you expect as the window function and UDV expressions do not evaluate in the order you might expect. This is the same reason that leads to an error being raised when you try to use a window function in the HAVING clause.  I cannot see why it comes out with the values that it does, but it is definitely related to evaluation order.
To make your current approach work you would need to have an additional step in another CTE:
WITH tasks AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Start_Date, End_Date
    FROM Projects
),
t2 AS (
    SELECT
        Start_Date,
        End_Date,
        LAG(End_Date) OVER (ORDER BY Start_Date) AS Prev_End_Date
    FROM tasks
)
SELECT t2.*, @rn := IF(Start_Date <=> Prev_End_Date, @rn, @rn + 1) AS cnt
FROM t2
JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) v
ORDER BY Start_Date;

As the value of cnt is only being used to group the Projects together based on consecutive End_dates, you can use the date - INTERVAL seq DAY approach:
WITH tasks AS (
    SELECT Start_Date, End_Date, End_Date - INTERVAL (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Start_Date)) DAY AS grp
    FROM Projects
)
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(Start_Date), ' ', MAX(End_Date)) AS Output
FROM tasks
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY COUNT(*), MIN(Start_Date);

Here's a db<>fiddle.
